# C# interpolated string with conditional-operator

Tags: c#, conditional-operator, string-interpolation

I tried to use the conditional operator inside an interpolated string, but because it has a colon in it, the compiler thinks that after the colon comes a format string.

```
$"test {foo ? "foo is true" : "foo is false"}";
```

How can I use this type of statement?
The only thing that comes to my mind is something like this:

```
var fooString = foo ? "foo is true" : "foo is false";
$"test {fooString}";
```

Comment: That's an [Interpolated string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dn961160.aspx). [Verbatim strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/362314fe.aspx) are those that start with `@"` and may contain characters that would normally need escaping.

Answer (score 203, accepted):

You need to put the string in parentheses within `{}`, so: `{(1 == 1 ? "yes" : "no")}`.

Answer (score 42):

```
$"test {(foo ? "foo is true" : "foo is false")}";
```

The code inside the parentheses returns a variable, and that's the only thing allowed inside the curly brackets. The colon ':' is a special character in string interpolation, hence it needs to be parenthesised.